# Create and manipulate underlined objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There is an idea to create an online music theory quiz. I have created a drawing in Inkscape and saved it in svg format. The file is used as an external source and has been added to HTML code.

The challenges I have are as follows:

1) How to make lines below treble staff activate (selected)?

2) How to put the names of the notes (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) into the underlined spaces?

3) How to name the repeated notes with the same letter (e.g. "F" is repeated 2 times in my sample)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing.svg" />

</body>
</html>
```

### [image]

4) I have converted svg into png to show a quiz draft.

Comment: What do you mean by activate? How do you load the data into the svg?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631455/how-do-you-make-an-svg-interactive

Comment: JNF: I think Activate means to select for further manipulation.I created a drawing in Inkscape, then saved it as svg file. RST: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

That actually involves quite complex javascripting :-) In your way, you'd have to do roughly the following:

- Download the SVG as "text" (or rather XML), via XHR (e.g. `$.get(image_library/grandstaff_drawing.svg)`)
- Parse the downloaded data and create an `<svg>` element in the document (as opposed to `<img>`
- Find all the notes and determine their position (on the `y` axis) and determine their name from that
- Create all the programming necessary for the *underlined spaces*

Probably an easier approach would be to create the stave in the browser and have the graphics of the key and notes merely as components. Then if you'll want to create e.g. an "CDE" note sequence, you'll be positioning the note components manually. You'll have to determine the `y` axis offsets of each note (e.g. 60px from top for C, 55px for D, 50px for E - assuming a line height of 10px), but it will be easier than determining the same from an Inkscape SVG. You'll have to learn a bit more about how SVG works, but you'd need that sooner or later anyway :-) So the steps would be the following

- Create an array in your browser, indicating the sequence to display (`['C', 'D', 'E']`)
- Create an `<svg>` element for the stave and insert all the notes into it by iterating over the note array (you might want to use some SVG framework, like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [D3](http://d3js.org))
- Create the programming necessary for the *underlined spaces* area, again by iterating over the array

The advantage of this approach is that you'll have the sequence in a JavaScript variable and from that you'll build **both** the stave and the *underlined spaces*, making it easier to determine if the user matched the notes correctly. Reconstructing the same variable from the SVG, as in the first approach, is going to be quite messy and prone to errors (as even a small difference between two Inkscape SVG will mess up your programming and you'll have to cater for it).

I'd say this is a *very* broad question, it's basically *how do I program this application*. JavaScript doesn't have a function `determineSequenceFromSvgStove` or `createBlankAreasWithFollowingCorrectAnswers` Try one of the approaches above and if you run into a trouble with how to implement some of the steps, ask about them.

Comment: veproza: thank you very much!!! I really appreciate  your explicit explanation and 2 strategies. I will work on both of them. The 2nd one looks more reasonable. If I am stuck, I will ask more specific questions. Have a great evening in beautiful Prague...